# Docker ubuntu:16.04 image needed vpn certificates to work correctly, but node:14-alpine3.12 does not?

Tags: node.js, docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, alpine-linux

For some reason the ubuntu:16.04 docker image would complain and not be able to download npm packages or install anything without the certificate installed and when I switched to node 14 alpine 3.12 it stopped being an issue.

Does anyone know why is this happening? Could it be related to ubuntu having more strict networking needs since it's a more complete suite vs alpine being super lightweight and connect directly to the host network?

I don't know how to explain what is happening here.

Additional info:

Old Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl ca-certificates
ADD vpn_root.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/vpn_root.crt
RUN chmod 644 /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/vpn_root.crt && update-ca-certificates
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app

EXPOSE 4000

CMD ["npm run start"]
```

New Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14-alpine3.12

WORKDIR /app

RUN apk update && apk add python3 py-pip

RUN pip install awscli 

COPY . .

RUN npm ci
```

Comment: The alpine image is much newer than the ubuntu image, which may be the reason alpine has all certificates needed to establish a ssl/tls connection to npm

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is because in the old one I was using a base image, while in the second one you are using an application image.  In order to install node and make it useable you need to install the CA Certificates.

So in the old one the certificates are being installed so you can get node from nodesource.com
In the new one I am using a node image so node doesn't need to be installed during docker build.

So since the installation is not happening in the base image anymore, instead of it being downloaded by the host/local machine it already has the certificates.